# Error al cargar Gridview ( NullPointerException)

Tags: android-studio

estoy trabajando en una app que es para un examen y me da este error al seleccionar la opcion del menu que muestra la lista de datos en el gridview

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

```
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
    at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:201)
```

tengo varias clases :

una clase base para los datos

```
public class Parqueos implements Serializable {

private String txtMatricula, txtIdCliente;

public Parqueos(String txtMatricula, String txtIdCliente) {
    this.txtMatricula = txtMatricula;
    this.txtIdCliente = txtIdCliente;
}

public String getTxtMatricula() {
    return txtMatricula;
}

public void setTxtMatricula(String txtMatricula) {
    this.txtMatricula = txtMatricula;
}

public String getTxtIdCliente() {
    return txtIdCliente;
}

public void setTxtIdCliente(String txtIdCliente) {
    this.txtIdCliente = txtIdCliente;
}
```

Un Servicio para cargar, guardar y eliminar los datos

```
public class ServicioParqueos {

private ArrayList<Parqueos> lista;
private String nombreArchivo;
private Context context;
private static ServicioParqueos instancia;

private ServicioParqueos(Context context) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    this.context = context;
    this.nombreArchivo = "data_parqueo.txt";
    try {
        lista = cargarDatosParqueo();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        lista = new ArrayList<>();
        guardarDatosParqueo(new Parqueos("Matricula",
                "ID del Cliente"));
    }
}

public static ServicioParqueos getInstance(Context context) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (instancia == null)
        instancia = new ServicioParqueos(context);
    return instancia;
}
```

El adaptador

```
public class AdaptadorParqueos extends ArrayAdapter<Parqueos> {

public AdaptadorParqueos(Context context, List<Parqueos> objets) {
    super(context, R.layout.grid_template, objets);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View item = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_template, null);
    }

    TextView textMatricula = item.findViewById(R.id.txt_matricula);
    TextView textIdUser = item.findViewById(R.id.txt_idCliente);
    textMatricula.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getTxtMatricula());
    textIdUser.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getTxtIdCliente());
    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Desea eliminar el regisro ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            try {
                                ServicioParqueos.getInstance(getContext()).eliminar(getItem(position));
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error al actualizar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                Log.e("ClassNotFound", e.getMessage());
                            }
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
        }
    });

    return item;
}
```

Y el fragment donde se muestra el gridview

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    GridView gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_parqueos);
    FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showEdttDialog();
        }
    });

    try {
        adapter = new AdaptadorParqueos(mContext,
                ServicioParqueos.getInstance(getActivity()).cargarDatosParqueo());
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter); //En el logcat marca esta linea en el error
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error al cargar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("clase no encontrada", e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Pido disculpas si me excedi con el codigo que muestro pero creo que son partes necesarias para ver el problema.
Desde ya muchas gracias...

Agrego el mensaje de error de LogCat completo :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

```
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
    at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:201)
    at com.xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.FragmentParqueos.onViewCreated(FragmentParqueos.java:81)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)


 public ArrayList<Parqueos> cargarDatosParqueo() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), nombreArchivo);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(context.openFileInput(nombreArchivo));
        //noinspection unchecked
        lista = (ArrayList<Parqueos>) input.readObject();
        input.close();

    } else {
        File archivo = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), nombreArchivo);
        if (archivo.exists() && archivo.isFile()) {
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo));
            //noinspection unchecked
            lista = (ArrayList<Parqueos>) inputStream.readObject();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    return lista;

}
```

Comment: En el LogCat ubicas un mensaje que inicie con "Caused by"?

Comment: No, solo eso, hace dias que estoy probando y revisando y no encuentro el problema

Comment: Agrega por favor CargarDatosParqueo().

Comment: en tu clase adaptador falta un metodo que retorna el tamaño de la lista que le pasas

Comment: en tu clase adaptador falta un metodo que retorna el tamaño de la lista que le pasas

Comment: Edite y puse el metodo CargarDatosParqueo()

Comment: En este método antes de "return lista" agrega:   if(lista == null) {
          lista = new ArrayList<Parqueos>();
        }    y prueba nuevamente, comenta que resultado obtienes.

Comment: Agregue esa linea que mencionaste y funciono perfectamente, Gracias! @Elenasys ...

Comment: @Marce72 asi es debes validar el caso en el cual el método retorne una vista con valor null, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el problema es que el método `cargarDatosParqueo()` esta retornando una lista con valor null, por esta razón puedes validar que en este caso retorne una vista vacia.

```
public ArrayList<Parqueos> cargarDatosParqueo() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), nombreArchivo);
    if (file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(context.openFileInput(nombreArchivo));
        //noinspection unchecked
        lista = (ArrayList<Parqueos>) input.readObject();
        input.close();

    } else {
        File archivo = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), nombreArchivo);
        if (archivo.exists() && archivo.isFile()) {
            ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(archivo));
            //noinspection unchecked
            lista = (ArrayList<Parqueos>) inputStream.readObject();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

   // valida evitar lista con valor null.
   if(lista == null) { 
       lista = new ArrayList<Parqueos>(); 
    } 

    return lista;

}
```